# jquery-ui file is not including in my project

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My jquery-ui-1.9.2.js file seems to not be included in my project, although it's in my BundleConfig.cs file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));    
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
```

However, the jquery-1.8.3.js is included properly.
The error I'm getting is: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'`

My selector is Ok, I checked with the browser's console.

Chrome shows me these js files in the script folder:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: is the file actually there can you click on js file and see the source

Comment: if you are just looking for a solution i would just referencer script in a regulat way do not see any disadvatgaes of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
SOLVED

I didn´t add this line `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` in my view.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") // Added
}
```